# XML in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to build an XML file from SQL Server data. I have the following Code:

```
 select (select 'White' as Color1,
 'Blue' as Color2,
 'Black' as Color3, 
  'green' as Color4 
   for XML Path ('Colors'), type),
  (select 'Apple' as Fruit1,
 'Grapes' as Fruit2,
 'Pinapple' as Fruit3, 
 'Melon' as Fruit4 
  for XML Path ('Fruits'), type)

  For XML Path (''), root ('SampleXML')
  go
```

This code produces the output below:

```
<SampleXML>
  <Colors>
   <Color1>White</Color1>
   <Color2>Blue</Color2>
   <Color3>Black</Color3>
   <Color4>green</Color4>
 </Colors>
 <Fruits>
  <Fruit1>Apple</Fruit1>
  <Fruit2>Grapes</Fruit2>
  <Fruit3>Pinapple</Fruit3>
  <Fruit4>Melon</Fruit4>
 </Fruits>
</SampleXML>
```

My intend is to have the output like this, I guess I am unable to add more elements.:

```
 <SampleXML>
 <ColorsandFruits>
    <Colors>
      <Color1>White</Color1>
      <Color2>Blue</Color2>
      <Color3>Black</Color3>
      <Color4>green</Color4>
   </Colors>
   <Fruits>
    <Fruit1>Apple</Fruit1>
    <Fruit2>Grapes</Fruit2>
    <Fruit3>Pinapple</Fruit3>
    <Fruit4>Melon</Fruit4>
    </Fruits>
  </ColorsandFruits>
  <ColorsandFruitsNumber2>
  <Colors>
    <Color1>White</Color1>
    <Color2>Blue</Color2>
    <Color3>Black</Color3>
    <Color4>green</Color4>
  </Colors>
  <Fruits>
    <Fruit1>Apple</Fruit1>
    <Fruit2>Grapes</Fruit2>
    <Fruit3>Pinapple</Fruit3>
    <Fruit4>Melon</Fruit4>
  </Fruits>
 </ColorsandFruitsNumber2>
 </SampleXML>
```

Comment: Have you tried using FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS? If you reconfigure your query to use a JOIN it should format the xml with multiple elements as you are expecting.

Comment: No, I haven't. Will try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that!

A structure like the following is enough:

```
<Fruits>
    <Fruit>Apple</Fruit>
    <Fruit>GrapesFruit>
    <Fruit>Pineapple</Fruit>
</Fruits>
```

This will be generated easily out of tabular data using `FOR XML PATH('Fruit'),ROOT('Fruits')`.

The element's order is an inherent part of the document and will not change. There is no need to number your elements. Later, when you read this, you'd have to write either one single call for each element or you'd have to deal with calls like `//*[predicate]`, which is slow and erronous.

The structure above you can query with

```
SELECT TheXml.value('(/Fruits/Fruit)[1]') AS Fruit1
      ,TheXml.value('(/Fruits/Fruit)[2]') AS Fruit2
      ...and so on...
```

It is a very bad desing to have numbered elements. If you really need these numbers, you might think about

```
<Fruits>
    <Fruit nr="1">Apple</Fruit>
    <Fruit nr="2">GrapesFruit>
    <Fruit nr="3">Pineapple</Fruit>
</Fruits>
```

The same with this

```
<ColorsandFruitsNumber2>
```

Don't do that again! Your data will have some kind of grouping key. Use this grouping key to **mark** a group with an attribute.

```
<ColorsandFruitsNumber groupkey="2">
```

You will find a lot of examples how to build nested XML using `FOR XML PATH`. I would avoid `AUTO`, as you have to rely on an engine to build the structure for you...

If this doesn't help you, please provide sample data (table format or - even better - as little script with `DECLARE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO`) and expected output.

Comment: Thanks, Shnugo! I added the expected output and the script in the question.

Comment: @user7675421 Your *expected output and script* does not really explain your needs. You will never use a `SELECT` with some hardcoded fruit names in real-life, will you? Your *expected output* is - structurally - absolutely wrong. I really do hope, that this is not the output you really want to achieve... Where is the data coming from?

Comment: Hi Shnugo, No this is just a sample, I thought it would be helpful. I will post Post the code and real sample data in few minutes. Thanks

Comment: Hi Shnugo, Sorry I haven't gotten to it yet.

Comment: @user7675421 Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!